# What kind of animation/drawing program do they use to make South Park?

Tags: production, animation, editing, south-park

In *6 Days to Air*, the documentary about the making of *South Park*, there is some great footage of the animators working on the characters in studio on wacom tablets. I couldn't tell what program it was. Does anyone know if it is a proprietary suite or something that can be purchased?

Comment: Shows a complete lack of any attempt at research. -1

Comment: Are you interested in the old hand made South Park or the newer episodes. Since for the old method they only used photos and cardboard. Furthermore, in the documentary you state they mention the software used...

Comment: If they mentioned it, I missed it. Apologies.

Comment: usually now they would use Adobe Photoshop & then put it into Autodesk Maya which are both costy programs, there would be alternatives but you could usually find some ways to get them for free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Park#Animation) on South Park:

> When the show began using computers, the cardboard cutouts were
>   scanned and re-drawn with CorelDRAW, then imported into PowerAnimator,
>   which was used with SGI workstations to animate the
>   characters. The workstations were linked to a 54-processor
>   render farm that could render 10 to 15 shots an hour.
>
> Beginning
>   with season five, the animators began using Maya instead of
>   PowerAnimator. The studio now runs a 120-processor render farm
>   that can produce 30 or more shots an hour.